# Chrome Developer Tools not working with popups

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I need to examine the HTML of a popup, which works by injecting new HTML into the document. However, if you off-click the popup it automatically closes. Chrome's Developer Tools requires you to change focus to that window, which causes an off-click.

I have figured out a workaround that helps but is ultimately insufficient. You can right-click on the injected HTML in DevTool's Elements tab, which allows you to copy the injected HTML before the browser recognizes the off-click. This helps, but doesn't allow you to fully examine the injected HTML.

(The following solution is insufficent)
[image]

Is there a solution that allows me to fully examine the popup's HTML?

Comment: Add a listener for some mouse events in Sources -> Event Listeners, then show the popup. It should pause before disappearing so you will examine it.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you give a more complete answer? I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Try [these solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+inspect+a+hover+popup+in+devtools).